# How to keep continue the same line if user input wrong?

Tags: java, while-loop

When I run the code, if you type character instead of integer it will prompt  to re enter again. But when we answer the 2nd or 3rd question, if wrong, it will ask you back to the 1st question. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks so much!

```
 while (true) {
       try {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println("Enter your monthly income (after tax and insurance): ");
           float monthlyIncome = input.nextFloat();

           System.out.println("Enter monthly cost for food: ");
           float monthlyFoods = input.nextFloat();

           System.out.println("Enter monthly cost for rent: ");
           float monthlyRent = input.nextFloat();

           System.out.println("Enter monthly cost for utilities " +
                   "(e.g. gas, phone bills, Internet): ");
           float monthlyUtilities = input.nextFloat();

           System.out.println("Enter monthly cost for shopping and hobbies: ");
           float monthlyHobbies = input.nextFloat();

           System.out.println("Do you plan for saving? (Enter 0 if not): ");
           float monthlySaving = input.nextFloat();

           monthlyExpenses(monthlyIncome, monthlyFoods, monthlyRent, 
                   monthlyUtilities, monthlyHobbies, monthlySaving);
           break;

    } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number only!");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes: more loops.

Comment: This is where methods come in really handy, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324730/if-a-user-types-in-a-number-that-isnt-available-the-following-message-is-printe/34324790#34324790)

Comment: Possibility would be to save all questions to array and count with a variable as index how many inputs were passed. Then in a second array you save the input and in the end you just need to convert it. Advantage: this is highly customisable and can be extended quite easy

Comment: Thanks guys! I got this fix! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code which you require to repeat in case of error inside the while loop; which makes your code seem like this:

```java
while (true) {
    float value;
    try {
    // code to get proper value from user & store in `value`     
    return value;
    } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number only!");
    }
  }
```

Now just move this code to a method:

```java
float getFloatValue(String questionDescription){

while (true) {
    float value;
    try {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println(questionDescription+": ");
      value = input.nextFloat();
      return value;
    } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number only!");
    }
  }
 return Float.NaN;
}
```

So finally the code for getting values looks like this:

```java
          float monthlyIncome = getFloatValue("Enter your monthly income (after tax and insurance)");

          float monthlyFoods = getFloatValue("Enter monthly cost for food");

          float monthlyRent = getFloatValue("Enter monthly cost for food");
          // get other values same as above
           monthlyExpenses(monthlyIncome, monthlyFoods, monthlyRent, 
                   monthlyUtilities, monthlyHobbies, monthlySaving);
```

The benefit of this approach is that only valid float values will be accepted and your code looks clean as well.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Now I figured it out and the code are much cleaner and make more sense! Thanks again for all the help you guys! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static float getFloat(String message)
  {
   float value;
   while (true) {
   try {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println(message);
       value=input.nextFloat();

  } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
    System.out.println("Please enter number only!");
  }}
  return value;
  }
    float monthlyIncome = getFloat("Enter your monthly income (after tax and insurance): ");
```

//Something like this

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility would be to save all questions to an array and count with a variable as index how many inputs were passed. Then in a second array you save the input and in the end you just need to convert it.

Advantage: this is highly customisable and can be extended quite easily.

The code would look something like that.

```
// Lots of Code here
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
String[] questions = {"How high...?", "[Insert questions 2]"}; // Put in all your questions here
float[] answers = new float[questions.length]; // array for answers
while(count < questions.length) {
    try {
        System.out.println(questions[count]);
        answers[count] = Float.parseFloat(scan.nextLine());
        count++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Bad doggo! No food for you tonight!"); // Tell the user he was a bad guy
    }
}
scan.close();
// If you want you can convert the answer array back to variables here but I think this way is easier
// More code
```